# How to put multiple photos in a compressed file after downloading php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code which downloads several images from private sites. I want all these images to be placed in a zip file.
how do I do this?

```
<?php
  $num = $_POST['num'];
  for ($i=1; $i <= $num ; $i++) { 
  $url_to_image = $_POST['img'].$i.'.jpg';
  $my_save_dir = "manga/" ;
  $filename = basename($url_to_image);
  $complete_save_loc = $my_save_dir . $filename;
  file_put_contents($complete_save_loc,
  file_get_contents($url_to_image));
  echo $i ."jpg". " /download" . '<br>';
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php-ZipArchive class. http://php.net/manual/de/zip.examples.php
If you dont have compiled your php-interpreter with the option --enable-zip you can use otherwise the php shell execution functions (exec, shell_exec, passthru) to use the host-systems zip.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `ZipArchive` like below

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

  $my_save_dir = "manga/files.zip";
  $zip->open($my_save_dir, ZipArchive::CREATE);

  $num = $_POST['num'];
  for ($i=1; $i <= $num ; $i++) { 
      $url_to_image = $_POST['img'].$i.'.jpg';

      $download_file = file_get_contents($url_to_image);
      $zip->addFromString(basename($url_to_image), $download_file);


   }

   $zip->close();
   echo $my_save_dir;
```

Comment: thanks but that for download the zip file. i want to the save the zip to a direction not to download